# How to read and write mixed metadata-data files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, metadata

Scientific data often come with a metadata section before the data section. I would like to read CSV files like the following example where I keep the top 5 rows separated as a metadata 'header' and do calculations on the remainder:

**Source**: stackoverflow.com

**Citation**: StackOverflow et al. 2021: How to import and export mixed metadata - data files using pandas.

**Date**: 17.02.21

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 9 |
| c | 4 | -2 |

After finishing I would like to write the dataset with the metadata 'header' on top to keep the original file structure.

**Source**: stackoverflow.com

**Citation**: StackOverflow et al. 2021: How to import and export mixed metadata - data files using pandas.

**Date**: 17.02.21

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 1 | 9 | 10 |
| c | 4 | -2 | 2 |

Comment: have you looked into `skiprows` and `nrows` in the `pd.read_csv` method? if the headers are consistent you can use this to split the dataframe into two parts then recombine then.

Comment: @Manakin. I did. However, the metadata section can be very elaborated with quite some formatting. Splitting using 'nrows' soon runs into problems. Is there a way to keep this chunk of the file 'as it is' and attach it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you escaped newlines,  so I removed in sample data

- open file and read contents
- take first five rows as meta header information
- do a DF manipulation
- save results back down to a file. Write meta data first followed by DF contents

```
from pathlib import Path

filetext = """Source: stackoverflow.com
Citation: stackoverflow et al. 2021: How to import and export mixed metadata - data files using pandas.
Date: 17.02.21
,,,
,,,
col_1,col_2,col_3
a,0,3
b,1,9
c,4,-2"""

p = Path.cwd().joinpath("so_science.txt")
with open(p, "w") as f:
    f.write(filetext)

# get file contents
with open(p, "r") as f: fc = f.read()
        
# first five rows are metadata
header = "\n".join(fc.split("\n")[:5])
# reset is a CSV
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(fc.split("\n")[5:])))
# modify DF
df["col_2"] = df["col_2"] + df["col_3"]

# write out meta-data and CSV
with open(p, "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{header}\n")
    df.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob Raymond, this solution works fine. I was surprised that there is no 'built-in' solution for that in pandas.